# Laplace transform of $f(\frac{t}{c})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, laplace-transform

Laplace transform of $f(\frac{t}{c})$. So in order for me to able to do the Laplace transform of the following function, what I did was the following:

$L(f(\frac{t}{c})) = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(\frac{t}{c})dt$

Now because I don't know of an easier way to solve this, what I did was integration by parts(feel free to correct me if there is an easier way to do this other than integration by parts)

Anyway, then I said:

Letting $dv = e^{-st}dt \implies v = \frac{-1}{s}e^{-st}$ and $u = f(\frac{t}{c}) \implies du = \frac{1}{c} f(\frac{t}{c})$

But what to do now? Am I even going in the right direction? The algebra gets considerably more mucky after this, and I do not know of a better way to solve it.

Comment: make the substitution $u=\frac t c$ or $t=cu$.

Comment: So I would get like $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-scu}f(u)c du$. And so then should I substitute some other variable for sc?

Comment: That is  nothing but the Laplace transform of $f$ at the point $sc$. Nothing more to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$L \left \{f\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)\right \}= \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-st}f(\frac{t}{c})dt$$
Substitute $t=uc \implies dt=cdu$:
$$L \left\{f\left(\frac{t}{c}\right)\right\} =c \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(sc)u}f(u)du=cF(sc)$$